# Using Ripple for assets accounting, loans, deposits, stock exchange, etc

Tags: ripple, accounting

If Ripple can handle money as exchanger, is it possible to use it for other financial operations like assets accounting, loans, deposits, stock exchange etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ripple has a [contract system](https://ripple.com/wiki/Contracts) under development. This will allow people to bind Ripple assets or accounts to a set of rules. This should be usable for most of the things mentioned in your question.

Loans, ideally, would be done just as negative balances on a pathway.